# Recursion in addFunction() of Volt (Phalcon)

Tags: recursion, phalcon, volt

As i have gone through the [documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html) provided by *Phalcon* for *Volt Templating Engine*. I found `addFuntion()` to add custom function in *Volt Compiler* to customize data. But regarding *n-level hierarchical menu / catalog case*, i need **recursion** in `addFunction()` which i am unable to make it work. Please guide me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

No problem in using recursion - remember that volt is compiled to PHP files. Also volt functions are plain PHP so:

```
$compiler->addFunction(
    'menu',
    function ($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs) {
        return 'MenuHelper::menu(' . $resolvedArgs . ')';
    }
);
```

Then why not:

```
class MenuHelper
{
    public static function menu($data)
    {
        if (empty($data)) {
            return '';
        }
        $out = '<ul>';
        foreach ($data as $name => $children) {
            $out .= '<li>' . $name . self::menu($children) . '</li>';
        }
        $out .= '</ul>';
        return $out;
    }
}
```

And view.volt:

```
{{ menu([ 'a' : [ 'a1' : [], 'a1' : ['a11' : [],'a12' : [],'a13' : [] ] ], 'b' : [] ]) }}
```

Will give you:

```
<ul><li>a<ul><li>a1<ul><li>a11</li><li>a12</li><li>a13</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>b</li></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks . . But I need a raw data so that i can use tags on my own from template . . Is there any other method to make it that way ? ?